# Count on Appengine (Expando models)

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to count some entries (over 1000) but when I connect via remote_api, using an Expando and doing a .count I get "1000L".

Is there a problem with Expando or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `.count()` method a big number as an argument. The argument is the maximum number of entities to count, and defaults to 1000.

Note that the datastore is very bad at counting and this won't scale well.

Comment: Yes, I know. I will also provide a .filter but I will probably have more than 1000 results. Isn't .count better than cursors if I just want to count?

Comment: I think default isn't 1000: "count() has no maximum limit. If you don't specify a limit, the datastore continues counting until it finishes counting or times out" - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_count

Comment: Don't always trust the docs; sometimes you need to RTFS: `def count(self, limit=1000, **kwargs):`

Comment: @Wooble this might be a limit only on the dev server since its datastore is very slooooow

Comment: @Shay: I'm fairly certain that the production servers use the exact same `google.appengine.ext.db` module as in the SDK, and the behavior can be confirmed in production trivially. In any case, the OP is definitely using that module, as remote_api is involved.

Comment: Interesting, as soon as I pass a limit > 1000 I get an assertion error. I'm also using remote_api to test out count() behavior. Anything less than 1000 returns fast. What could be the problem?